# opt command not working [LLVM]

Tags: software-installation, symbolic-link

My linking looks broken. It's showing below error.

```
$ opt
The program 'opt' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt-get install llvm
```

and `apt-get install llvm-3.6` shows that:

```
$ apt-get install llvm-3.6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
llvm-3.6 is already the newest version.
```

What am I missing here?

**Edit**

With opt, even llvm is also broken. Could anyone please clear that as well?

```
$ apt-cache policy llvm
llvm:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:3.4-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
    1:3.4-0ubuntu1 0
    500 http://my.org.url/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

`which opt` showing nothing.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy llvm` and `which opt`

Comment: The output of `apt-cache policy llvm`. Not `llvm-3.6` and the output of `which opt`

Comment: @A.B. I would like to know the solution as well as reason to downvote.

Comment: Again, install `llvm` as described in my answer. The reason for the downvote, I can not tell you. For this you have to know who it was. And that's not possible.

Comment: @A.B. Thanks A.B. The problem with installing llvm directly is: it gives me llvm-3.4 by default, to install llvm-3.6 I need to specify as `apt-get install llvm-3.6`.  I am assuming that might be because it goes by default to our org repo for finding any packages.

Comment: Ok, my last try: **I N S T A L L** the package `llvm`

Answer (score 3):

The binary (symbolic link) `/usr/bin/opt` is in the package `llvm`. Therefore install with

```
sudo apt-get install llvm
```

The installation of this package creates a symbolic link

```
/usr/bin/opt -> ../lib/llvm-3.6/bin/opt
```

Or create the link via

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/llvm-3.6/bin/opt /usr/bin/opt
```

---

You can check this via `apt-file`

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
sudo apt-file update
apt-file search --regex /opt$
```

*Sample output*

```
glibc-source: /usr/src/glibc/debian/control.in/opt
llvm: /usr/bin/opt
llvm-3.4: /usr/lib/llvm-3.4/bin/opt
llvm-3.5: /usr/lib/llvm-3.5/bin/opt
llvm-3.6: /usr/lib/llvm-3.6/bin/opt
scsh-0.6: /usr/lib/scsh-0.6/opt
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, it is also not working for `llvm` command. Since I tried for `clang` as well, it was straight forward with [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/584711/clang-and-clang-not-found-after-installing-the-clang-3-5-package) question, but in same way, its difficult to figure out for `llvm`.

Comment: What do you mean with "I think", have you installed the `llvm` package?

Comment: Yes, I have already installed it, as it's clear from question itself. (I removed unclear part of my comment as well. :) )

Comment: Has this been solved? Although I can confirm your output of apt-file, the file `/usr/lib/llvm-4.0/bin/opt` simply does *not* exist. I install llvm and llvm-dev.